# Data corruption in Vala with ThreadPool

Tags: segmentation-fault, arrays, threadpool, vala

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to queue network packets to be processed.  I have a ThreadPool with a maximum of 25 threads that processes these packets when they are available.  However, when passing the packet data (encapsulated in a class) to the thread_proc method associated with the ThreadPool, the data is being corrupted.  I declare my ThreadPool variable like so:

```
pool = new ThreadPool<Packet>((Func<Packet>)thread_proc, 25, false);
```

This is the thread method that checks the available packets:

```
void* run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var packet = packets.poll();

        try
        {
            pool.push(packet);
        }
        catch (ThreadError e)
        {
            error(e.message);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

"packets" is a BlockingQueue (custom blocking queue using a mutex) of the following class:

```
class Packet : Object
{
    public unowned ClientHandler client;
    public uint8[] data;
    public int index;
    public int size;

    public Packet(ClientHandler client, uint8[] data, int index, int size)
    {
        this.client = client;
        this.data = data;
        this.index = index;
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

The above class is what contains the actual packet data (the "data" var).  By the time the Packet instance gets around to thread_proc, the variable values are all wrong...

Any help as to why this is happening and a possible solution would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

~ Michael K.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated C to make sure Vala is doing appropriate memory management? You could also try running the program under valgrind to ensure it is not using freed memoory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pushed [a commit](http://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/commit/?id=d284317520032cf6f94529cc87ce95d178618af1) to valac git which will let Vala automatically manage the data.  It would have broken backwards compatibility, so you'll have to use the new constructor (ThreadPool.with_owned_data) and method (add instead of push).

If you want to avoid a dependency on valac git, you can just do a `packet.ref ()` before pushing it, then `packet.unref ()` at the end of your callback (`thread_proc`).  There is an example at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=214884.

Note that casting thread_proc in the ThreadPool constructor could break the new memory management stuff.  Frankly, you should really just avoid casting delegates... it's a great way to get in trouble.  It's much better to just fix your function (`thread_proc` in this case) to have the correct signature.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Manually increasing the reference counter did it for me :)  I also did as you advised and removed the cast to Func<Packet> as it was unnecessary.  It must have been an oversight of mine when going by the ThreadPool example I saw.